# Retrieving PFObject using key

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm having trouble retrieving the PFObject successfully using a key. The object nil in the end:

```
    var object = PFObject(className:"Topic")
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Topic")
    query.whereKey("title", equalTo:"Default")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if object != nil {
            NSLog("The getFirstObject request failed.")
        } else {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog("Successfully retrieved the object.")
        }
    }
```

Using this to create the follow relation

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                NetworkManager.sharedInstance.follow(object, completionHandler: {
                    (error) -> () in
                    if error == nil {
                    }
                    else {
                        println("follow topic failure")
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                println("signup failure")
            }
        }
    }
```

To test if the retrieval of the object was successful:

```
    println("this is the title of the default topic")
    println(object["title"] as String)
```

Console prints:

```
this is the title of the default topic
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Where are you putting those `println`s?

Comment: just before the user.signupinbackgroundwithblock. i don't think there's an issue with that

Comment: if it's outside of your getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock that's definitely the issue... I'll explain... One sec...

Comment: does that mean i'm not saving retrieved PFObject as object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're attempting to print the `object["title"]` outside of your `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` block, your current code's going to cause you a few issues.

(1) I think you're attempting to print from the `object` PFObject you created at the top of your code, i.e. `var object = PFObject(className:"Topic")`, not the `object` created by your `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` for use within its scope; but that `PFObject object` outside of `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` was never retrieved.

(2) `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` block is run asynchronously, meaning it's being fetched in the background and may not be available immediately; so even if the `PFObject object` outside of `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` was set to contain the `PFObject object` returned by `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock`, you can't guarantee that the object will be ready for use outside of the block since `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` can still be fetching the object when you attempt to print `object["title"]` outside of the block.

(3) Even in your block, it seems as if you're not understand your conditionals since `if object != nil` you're printing that the request has failed when it's actually suceeded.

Here's what I suggest doing to print out your object and to use that same `object` for `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock`:

```
// fetchedObject is a global variable created to store
// the retrieved object, but make sure the 
// getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock has had time to
// fetch the object before trying to use fetchedObject;
// also check to make sure it's non-nil
var fetchedObject:PFObject!

func signUp () {

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Topic")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if object != nil {

            // Save the object as a global object for use
            // outside of this method
            self.fetchedObject = object

            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved the object.")
            println("This is the title of the default topic:")
            if let defaultTopic:String = object["title"] as? String {
                println(defaultTopic)
            }

            user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    NetworkManager.sharedInstance.follow(object, completionHandler: {
                        (error) -> () in
                        if error == nil {
                        }
                        else {
                            println("follow topic failure")
                        }
                    })
                }
                else {
                    println("signup failure")
                }
            }
        } else {
            println("The getFirstObject request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. How could I call the PFObject, object, outside of the block? I think it's still limited to the scope of the block.

Comment: @user2913669 That's what I'm trying to explain with point #2. You can't use the PFObject outside of the block during that method since it's being fetched in the background and may not be available immediately.

Comment: Thanks, in that case it won't be possible to call the PFObject I retrieved outside of the block? What is the typical solution to working around this?

Comment: Sidenote: I just noticed your name. Saw your interview on Forbes!! Wow I am honored.

Comment: @user2913669 Oh, cool. Thanks :) But why do you absolutely need to use the variable outside of the block? If you want to use it in a different method after enough time has passed to perform the fetch, then you can store the object as a global variable for use elsewhere. But it you want to access the object outside of the block but within the same method, you can't (and shouldn't) do it. In most cases, you can easily put any code that depends on the retrieval of that object within the async block to guarantee its availability.

Comment: I was trying to call the PFObject in a different block. `NetworkManager.sharedInstance.follow(object, completionHandler: {`

Comment: @user2913669 Yep, so you have to put that block within your other block... I'll update my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. However, is it possible to create a function around the query so that I can retrieve PFObjects with different variables in the future?

Comment: @user2913669 Yep, sure. For example instead of `query.whereKey("title", equalTo:"Default")`, either the key ("title") or "equal to" value ("Default") can be set with an NSString variable passed in as a parameter instead.

Comment: But even if I created a separate function, wouldn't I still run into the issue of having to execute the `user.signup block` **inside** the query? oh i see, let me check the update

Comment: @user2913669 Oh, I misunderstood you. One sec. I'll update again. Yes, you can use the same PFObject in the future as long as you store it as a global variable. Just check to make sure it's been fetched and exists before using it.

Comment: @user2913669 Updated to show you how you can create a global variable (i.e. fetchedObject) for use in other methods. But again make sure it's been fetched and exists before using it.

Comment: I'm going to look over your answer some more, but I understand now.  Thanks 1000x for your time and help!

Comment: @user2913669 No problem. :) Feel free to post here again if you have anymore issue with this code.

Comment: Quick question, I was trying out the global variable alternative and ran into this error: `'AuthViewController' does not have a member named 'fetchedObject'` on `self.fetchedObject = object`

Comment: @user2913669 Did you also add the `var fetchedObject:PFObject!` line outside of your functions?

Comment: @user2913669 No... Could you post a screenshot of your current code?

Comment: You're right. sorry, I was trying the call the fetchedObject outside the function. I figured out the issue. thanks again for the help! update: not sure if there was an issue with your code, but after some editing, it is working for me :)